# Getting "Unsupported content type" when opening Java file in Eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I have this one java file in my Eclipse(Luna) project, which whenever I try to open it, I get an "unsupported content type" message.

Despite this, the code seems to run fine.  The only problem is that the Java editor is disabled, making it hard to change anything.  The file has a .java extension, and when I open up the "properties" dialog it's listed as a java file.

It seems to compile and run just fine, and it opens up in Notepad++ as a fully formatted java file, so apparently Notepad++ doesn't seem to have a problem with it.  Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: has the error log an entry for that problem?

Comment: "eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui
Warning
Wed Sep 02 14:08:26 PDT 2015
StructuredTextEditor being used without StructuredDocument

Input Name: PTGUI.java

Unexpected IDocumentProvider implementation: org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider

Comment: And then eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui
Warning
Wed Sep 02 14:08:26 PDT 2015
        Unexpected IDocument implementation: org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument

Comment: When you right-click on the file, and look in the Open With menu, are you *actually* opening it in the Java Editor?

Comment: Well, when I did that , it worked.  It only errored out when I left-clicked on the file in the Project Explorer.   Still not sure why it did that, but at least now I have a workaround.  Thanks.